# How do I ignore Linux on boot?

Tags: boot, drivers, windows, dual-boot, kali-linux

I have Windows 10 on my primary SSD and Kali Linux on a HDD. I need the slot with Linux HDD temporarily to be used with Windows, but the problem is that it tries to boot from the missing drive. How do I ignore the missing OS?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. Did you obliterate the Linux partition on the HDD ? If you did so, when do you get missing OS message ? The question doesn't sound coherent to me. You need to explain what you did so far.

Comment: @MelBurslan This is obviously (to me at least) a laptop, where you can slide out the harddrive from its slot/bay and put in a CD or other drive.

Comment: Changing boot priority/order in your system's BIOS to the Windows 10 drive could help

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Kali Linux after Windows 10, then the boot process for Windows is most likely going through the grub bootloader installed with Kali.

That probably means your SSDs bootsector loads grub from HDD and that redirects (when selecting Windows) to SSD for further booting.

You cannot remove the HDD in such a situation without breaking the boot process as you will remove grub and its configuration menu. What you would need to do beforehand is restore the windows bootsector on the SSD, and restore it when you want to use Kali again.

I recommend you save the current bootsector to some USB stick, so you can restore it after booting from a Live USB installation (unless you have a way to restore the bootsector from within Windows).